# Emmet to Handlebars (.hbs) files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code and lovin' it. The major "problem" I am experiencing now is straight simple: *how do I use Emmet sinppets for .hbs files?* Is there any way?

As far as I know, it is only available on `.html` and `.css` syntaxes—but I want more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Thanks for your feedback, I logged a bug for us to add support to handlebars and we can provide a fix for the next update.</s>

**Update for our VS Code 1.0 release:**

This has been implemented now!

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin! Do you have any thoughts about when this update will be launched?

Comment: I would assume in around 2 weeks. We have a release schedule of 3 weeks typically.

Answer (score 1):

I've just committed the change to enable emmet for .hbs files. The change will be in the next updated scheduled in about 1 week.